# Mocking default type variable of abstract class

Tags: mocking, abstract-class, default, jmockit

Lets say I have one abstract class which is extended by its sub class and I want to mock an class which is used in protected data type in the super class. The problem is the class which needs to be mocked is of default data type so it cannot be accessed outside the package. Let me give an example to make my point clear. Thanks for your help.

```
    class protectedVariableClass{

    public SomeObject someObject1;
    public SomeObject someObject2;  
    }

    public abstract class superClass {

    protected protectedVariableClass protectedVariableClass;

    ..................
    .................
    }

    public class subClass extends superClass {

    protected boolean someMethod() {
    protectedVariableClass.someObject1.printValue;
    }

    }
```

Now when I try to test it using Jmockit I am not able to create a mock for Protected variable of a super class.

```
    public class SubClassTest{

    @Mocked
    private protectedVariableClass mockedObject; // Cannot access the class with default data type outside package.

    @Test
    public void testClass {
    subClass s1 = new subClass();
    s1.someMethod();
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`realClassName`](http://jmockit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/www/javadoc/mockit/Mocked.html#realClassName()) attribute of `@Mocked`, but the best solution would be to *not* mock the non-accessible class.

The fact that some class you want to test uses a package-private class is usually just an implementation detail, and as such it should not appear in test code. The same applies to `private` methods called by the tested code: they should not be mocked.